# How to model a curved element in 4NEC2

Tags: antenna-modeling

I am in kindergarten with 4NEC2 and trying to model a Gray-Hoverman TV antenna. I have someone else's model and understand most of the file parameters. I have added VHF elements that have S curves at each end but I can't find any info as to how to model the curves.
I also want to model a folded dipole. Is there any hope for me?
Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: Please remember to click the "check" mark if you received an adequate answer to your question. This takes it off the list of unanswered questions and helps with housekeeping.

Answer (score 1):

Curves must be broken into a series of straight segments. The accuracy of your results will depend on the size of the segments relative to the wavelength of operation.

For the example below, I used the Create > Loop feature of [EZNEC](https://eznec.com/) to produce numbered segments, each of which is further broken down (see the green dots), then reconfigured into an "S" shape:

[image]

There are many other means and tools for doing this. I have used spreadsheets to generate segment endpoints, a feature which is now powerfully amplified in [AutoEZ](https://ac6la.com/autoez.html) by [AC6LA](https://ac6la.com/) (I take no credit for this, I just appreciate and routinely use the tool's many powerful features). The spreadsheet-like formula features of [4NEC2](https://www.qsl.net/4nec2/) could also be used in this application.

I have no affiliation with any of the products mentioned in this post.

Comment: thanks Brian, I have this modeled in Sketchup and was able to get coord points so I could enter it into a .NEC file. 4NEC2 didn't like a 6.35mm wire and I and to reduce it to 2mm to get rid of errors but I still have warnings. But given my lack of knowledge about this program, I am surprised I have gotten this far.